# How to Partial commitSync when consume batch in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are batch consuming with kafka. we consume X messages put them on MYSQL then commit them.

Times to times we have partial insertions to MYSQL (duplicate records, other failures, etc..)

using this example from the docs:

```
List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            buffer.add(record);
        }
        if (buffer.size() >= minBatchSize) {
            insertIntoDb(buffer);
            consumer.commitSync();
            buffer.clear();
        }
```

We want to commitSync only the successful records while having kafka replay the failures.

But I cant understand how to do this as the api got only commitSync() on the whole batch.

Ideas?

Comment: you can use other flavors of `commitSync` (see https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync--) specifying the offset or configure your poll to fetch only 1 message.

Comment: Why not use Kafka Connect JDBC Sink to handle this logic for you?

Comment: @cricket_007 does kafka connect jdbc sink got redelivery incase of any issues?

Comment: Depends on the issue, but in the general case, yes. And it tracks offsets more closely than relying on buffer sizes

Answer (score 3):

In Kafka you don't commit specific records, ie you can't mark offset N as processed and offset N-1 as not processed. Instead by committing offset N, you indicates you've processed all records up to N.

Things you can do when failing to process offset N:

- Commit N-1 (using [`commitSync(java.util.Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.util.Map-)) and retry processing offset N as you still have it in memory. Only once N has successfully been process you commit N and move to newer records.
- Assuming you run in a Sink Connector in Kafka Connect, upon failure to process N you can forward the record to Connect's Deal Letter Queue. Otherwise push it back to another topic for later processing. This temporarily skips offset N (you could also drop it if that's an option).

You can also do a mix of both, attempt a few retries, but if it's not possible to process this record, save/drop it and keep processing newer records.